# How to return every +2 item in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects :

```
const routes = [
{ id: 1, path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
{ id: 2, path: "/about", element: <AboutPage /> },
{ id: 3, path: "/review", element: <ReviewPage /> },
];
```

I have to loop though the array by the id and get every +2 item.
So by explanation the first item would be : id : 1
then we do +2 and next item is id:3

**third item** : id : 2

**fourth item** : id : 1

**fifth item** : id : 3
etc...

How would that be implemented?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I tried getting all the items that are % 2 == 0 but in the end I get only the first and third id. If you would do by incrementing by 2, id : 2 would eventually appear in the list

Comment: Can you show how does your loop look right now? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here : routes.filter((route) => {
    return route.id % 2 === 1;
  });                                   But as I said I only get the first and third element, so Im trying to understand how to loop only though 2 and not get only the numbers % 2

Comment: You want to get more than 3 items even though your input only has 3 items? And it repeats using that pattern? Like, the `nth` item has an id of `(1+n*2) % 3 +1`. Is there a maximum n?

Comment: I want to get that id every time I click a button. There is no maximum n. It should work as long as I click the button

Comment: Save the index as a state of your program. Then when the button is clicked, update the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in this case

```js
const routes = [{id:1,path:"/",element:"<HomePage />"},{id:2,path:"/about",element:"<AboutPage />" },{ id:3,path:"/review",element:"<ReviewPage />" }];

const makeNext = (size, step = 2) => {
    let i = size - step;
    
    return () => {
        i += step;
        if (i >= size) i -= size; 
        return i;
    }
};

const nextId = makeNext(routes.length);

console.log(routes[nextId()]);
console.log(routes[nextId()]);
console.log(routes[nextId()]);
console.log(routes[nextId()]);
console.log(routes[nextId()]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will be in need to use a while until the condition you want and take an value like i = 1 (for example). Next you should take your element id = i and add to i + 2. And to finish you just need to verify if (i > 3) in this case you set i = i - 3. The code should work, here is an example :

```
const routes = [
{ id: 1, path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
{ id: 2, path: "/about", element: <AboutPage /> },
{ id: 3, path: "/review", element: <ReviewPage /> },
];

i = 1
while (True) {
    console.log(routes[i]);
    i += 2;
    if (i > 3) { i -= 3}
}
```

Comment: Why not do `routes.length` instead of 3, and subtract `i -= routes.length`? Just in case the array isn't always that size

Comment: If you use while(true) without a break, the program will just be stuck there

Comment: It's for that reason that I said in my post "the condition you want" but to show an example I tried to create a code without testing it that works...

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this could be of help to you.

https://jsfiddle.net/codyrowirthpaige/gr3cy4ek/

```js
const arr = [
1,2,3,4
    ];
// return every second item in the array
function everySecond(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    console.log(newArr)
    return newArr;
    }
    
everySecond(arr);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).